# Create Mutex throws Error The system cannot open the device or file specified

Tags: c#, .net, openshift, redhat

I have a dotnet WebApi application which is running on OpenShift (RHEL).
To build the application I am using source2image strategy with the RedHat Image.

https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi8/dotnet-60/6182efb9be25a74c00923849

https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore

After updating to .net 6.0-22 I am getting following error when I am trying to create a Mutex:

> System.IO.IOException: The system cannot open the device or file specified. : 'MutexName'
> at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
> at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name)
> at Network.Services.GitService.AddSchedule(String region, String site, ScheduleConfigurationViewModel configuration, String commitMessage) in /opt/app-root/src/Src/Infrastructure/Network/Services/GitService.cs:line 122
> at WebApi.Controllers.ConfigurationController.Post(String assetId, String commitMessage) in /opt/app-root/src/Src/WebApi/Controllers/ConfigurationController.cs:line 236
> at lambda_method259(Closure, Object)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at WebApi.Common.CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ILogger`1 logger, ICurrentUserService currentUserService) in /opt/app-root/src/Src/WebApi/Common/CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 33
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Code Fragment where the error is thrown:

```
public void AddSchedule(string region, string site, ScheduleConfigurationViewModel configuration, string commitMessage)
{
    using var mutex = new Mutex(false, MutexName);
    var hasHandle = false;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            hasHandle = mutex.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5), false);
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException)
        {
            // Log the fact that the mutex was abandoned in another process,
            // it will still get acquired
            hasHandle = true;
        }


        var repoDir = Clone();
        Pull();
        WriteScheduleFile(repoDir, configuration);
        AddAll();
        Commit(commitMessage);
        Push();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hasHandle)
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Edit

Below you can see the permissions of the mentioned folders. There is a session folder where I don't have rights. Is this the problem?

```
ls -la /
```

[image: /tmp]

```
ls -la /tmp
```

[image: /tmp/.dotnet]

```
ls -la /tmp/.dotnet/shm
```

[image: /tmp/.dotnet/shm]

Rights before the update:

```
ls -la /tmp/.dotnet/shm
```

[image: /tmp/.dotnet/shm]

### Workaround

Add `.s2i/bin` folder to the source repo with an `assemble` file with following content.

This will delete the session folder from the build process.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Before assembling"

/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble
rc=$?

if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "After successful assembling"
    echo "Delete /tmp/.dotnet/shm/*"
    rm -rf /tmp/.dotnet/shm/*
else
    echo "After failed assembling"
fi

exit $rc
```

Comment: Try to check permissions on /tmp, /tmp/.dotnet and subdirectories, that's where mutex related files are stored by .NET.

Comment: Evk, can you provide a link for that information? The dotnet source code shows a pinvoke call and that's where my trail ended.